# Does C++ new operator use malloc() underneath?

Tags: c++

In other words, does it or not do a `malloc()` syscall everytime it is called ? (maybe by allocation a large chunk in advance)

Comment: Implementation dependent I imagine.

Comment: malloc is not a system call, it's a function in the Standard C library.

Comment: @Neil Adopted that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your edit to the title seems to change the intent of the question.  I don't think that is the question the OP was asking.

Comment: @Miles Why exactly?

Comment: OP is asking if calls to `operator new` correspond one-to-one with `malloc` calls, not whether or not it uses `malloc` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Before C++14 the standard prohibited the implementation from combining allocations.  Therefor each `new` expression did correspond one-to-one with a call to some system allocation function (possibly `malloc`).

C++14 [relaxed this restriction](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html) in some cases.  It's now possible for the implementation to combine allocations if the lifetime of one is strictly within the lifetime of the other.  This is a fairly narrow restriction though, so I expect allocations don't actually get combined all that often.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, does it or not do a `malloc()` syscall everytime it is called?

It's actually implementation dependend. But usually implementations of `new` will make use of `malloc()` syscalls/c-library bindings.

> (maybe by allocation a large chunk in advance)

Yes, you have to consider that as a drawback. Frequently calling something like

```
char* newChar = new char();
```

may clutter your dynamic storage space unnecessarily with larger chunks allocated, than a single `char` would need.

If you want to override that behavior for some more efficient memory management, you can always use [*placement `new`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is implementation defined. However, I would think that a high-performance C++ implementation would probably not use malloc(), but would use OS-specific memory allocation APIs or system calls (which malloc() must itself use). After all, why add an extra function call to every memory allocation? But I have no hard evidence for this.