# Will mallopt() also control the behavior of C++ native "new"?

Tags: c++, c, linux

According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html, "The mallopt() function adjusts parameters that control the behavior of the memory-allocation functions", I want to know will it also affect the behavior of C++ native "new" for memory allocation?

Comment: Probably it depends on the answer to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957649/does-c-new-operator-use-malloc-underneath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C++ new operator use malloc() underneath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957649/does-c-new-operator-use-malloc-underneath)

Comment: I would love to learn about the answer too. The `libstdc++` is over briefing and nowhere could I find the answer.